# Testing a fragment that uses bottom navigation view of a parent activity

Tags: android, testing, fragment, bottomnavigationview, uitest

I am trying to do some UI testing in isolation  on some fragments that uses a shared Bottom navigation view from MainActivity, basically used to navigate and to scroll up and down, but my tests fails with nullpointerException basically because the buttons inside the bottom navigation view are not found in the fragment layout.
My question is how to pass these layouts belonging to mainactivity to the fragmentTest class.

Comment: As abstract as this question is written, it might be difficult to answer. Please add the least code required to reproduce the problem, in case you'd like to see a reliable answer; else I could only close it as duplicate of: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) (`FragmentScenario` might be the wrong approach).

Comment: I am trying to use fragment Scenario val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<FeedFragment>( fragmentArgs = null,factory = fragmentFactory) what other choice do i have ? for example i used         fab = (activity as? AppCompatActivity)!!.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton)
to access the fab inside the bottom nav view of the main activity from within the fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FragmentScenario` is the wrong approach, because a `Fragment` should not even depend on the parent `Activity` (and if it does, always check with `instanceof` or `is`, which one `Activity` it actually had been attached to). Better instrument the parent `Activity` with an [`ActivityTestRule`](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-rules) instead, because a `FragmentScenario` uses it's own mock `Activity` and so you'll never get a handle to the expected one parent `Activity` (that's intentional, in order to rule out rigid dependencies to the parent `Activity`). Just set a break-point inside your current test's code, in order to see that there is no `BottomNavigationView` present, because it hasn't been inflated.

There's also a new [`ActivityScenario`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario) (which is currently still in beta stage).